# Local variable have value '.!toplevel.!calendar.!frame' on VARIABLES section visual studio code when debugging python code

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter, visual-studio-code

In this project I want to customize [tkcalendar](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar) python for my own purpose.
When I tracking line by line, I wondered on line 420 which are common `ttk.Frame` from tkinter set a `self.header` class attributes. The `self.header` object now has `_w` key object which contain value that I dont even know the meaning is.

I want to know the meaning of this value format that I red underlined.

Thank you for your help.

[image: local variable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter is a wrapper around an embedded tcl/tk interpreter. Every tkinter widget is associated with a lower level tcl/tk widget. The `_w` attribute is the name of this low level tcl/tk widget.

The naming convention of tcl/tk widgets is similar to a filesytem path, except it uses `.` instead of `/`. Thus, the root window is a leading `.`, and subsequent children are separated by `.`. Tcl lets you use any character you want for the name, except for `.`.

In recent versions of tkinter, tkinter chooses names by converting the widget class to lowercase, and prefixing it with `!`. If there is already a widget by that name it appends a number (eg: `.!frame`, `.!frame2`, etc)

Your specific example looks like this:

```
.!toplevel.!calendar.!frame
^^         ^         ^
||         |         +- Frame widget, child of the Calendar
||         +-Calendar widget, child of the Toplevel
|+-Toplevel widget, child of the root window
+-root window
```

Although it's rarely done, you can supply your own widget names to make this internal name more meaningful. Consider this example:

```
root = tk.Tk()
dialog = tk.Toplevel(root, name="custom-dialog")
buttons = tk.Frame(dialog, name="button-frame")
ok = tk.Button(buttons, name="ok-button")
```

With the above code, the "ok" button will have the following internal name:

```
.custom-dialog.button-frame.ok-button
```